# I have a problem in doubley-linked-list by C Programming.(Error of next Pointer)

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault, doubly-linked-list

```
struct someEvent
{
    int id;
    int shouldRemove;
    struct someEvent *prev;
    struct someEvent *next;
} * someEvent;


struct someEvent *someEventQueue = NULL;


int main(){

struct someEvent **curr5 = &someEventQueue;
                while ((*curr5) != NULL)
                {
                    if ((*curr5)->shouldRemove == 1)
                    {
                        tmpflag = 1;
                        if ((*curr5)->prev == NULL && (*curr5)->next == NULL)
                        {
                            (*curr5) = NULL;
                        }
                        else if ((*curr5)->prev == NULL)
                        {
                            (*curr5) = (*curr5)->next;
                            (*curr5)->prev = NULL;
                            //(*curr5)->prev->next = (*curr5)->next;
                        }
                        else if ((*curr5)->next == NULL)
                        {
                            (*curr5)->prev->next = NULL;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            (*curr5)->prev->next = (*curr5)->next;
                            (*curr5)->next->prev = (*curr5)->prev;
                        }
                    }
                    if (tmpflag == 1)
                    {

                        break;
                    }

                    curr5 = &(*curr5)->next;
                }



  }
```

I made my code like this. I want to delete node which shouldRemove is 1.

[image]

This picture is someEventQueue. I want to delete node which id is 2.

[image]

I want this result. But, My result has some wrong...

[image]

This picture is result of my code. After debugging I found why It has error. `(*curr5)->prev->next = (*curr5)->next;` this part works great. But, after this part `(*curr5)` is changed to `(*curr5)->next` and  `(*curr5)->next->prev = (*curr5)->prev;` this code returns segmentation error. I don't know why this kind of change is happened. For solving this problem, I add `(*curr5)=(*curr5)->prev;` between `(*curr5)->prev->next = (*curr5)->next;` and `(*curr5)->next->prev = (*curr5)->prev;`. Then, this falls infinite loop... I think my code has no error, but I don't know why (*curr5) is changed after  `(*curr5)->prev->next = (*curr5)->next;`. I need some advice.

Comment: Unrelated, was it your intention for this code to declare a global variable `someEvent` of type `struct someEvent *` ? If not (i.e. if you clipped out the typedef when pasting this to SO), then stop hiding pointers in typedefs; its nearly always a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You're making this more complicated than it need be. The code *appears* to want to remove the first node in the list that has the `shouldRemove` flag set, then stop. Node management in duo-linked lists is about two things:

- the pointer that gets you there.
- the node, if any, that holds that pointer.

I.e.

```
int main()
{
    struct someEvent **curr = &someEventQueue;
    struct someEvent *prev = NULL;

    while (*curr)
    {
        if ((*curr)->shouldRemove)
        {
            struct someEvent *tmp = *curr;
            *curr = tmp->next;
            if (tmp->next)
                tmp->next->prev = prev;

            // added to prevent memory leak. remove if these are
            //  maintained somewhere else.
            free(tmp);

            break;
        }
        else
        {
            prev = *curr;
            curr = &(*curr)->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Worth noting, you can remove *all* nodes with the `shouldRemove` flag set by removing the `break;` in the above loop.